# How can I make the left margin bigger?

Tags: html, css, margin

I would like to move the h1 text more to the middle of the screen, but the left margin isn't working properly. I've tried increasing and decreasing the size of the margin (both with pixels and percentages) but it has no effect on the page. I've also tried changing the background colour to see if I just forgot to end the previous line or I had the wrong dimensions, and the colour changed (so no errors there). I've also ran both the HTML and the CSS code through their respective validators and there's no errors related to the margin/header.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <h1><span style="font-size: 50px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ffffff; color:#f5cec9;">Welcome!</span><br>What do you want to make?</h1>
```

and the CSS code:

```css
    img, img.menui {
        width: 165px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    div, div.cake, div.menu {
        width: 80%;
        height: 60%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-top: 7%;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        /*margin-left: 428769875937548px;*/
    }
```

```html
    <div class="menu">
        <h1><span style="font-size: 50px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ffffff; color:#f5cec9;">Welcome!</span><br>What do you want to make?</h1>
    </div>
```

For more context you can find the website [here](https://Eindproduct-thatbellastuffz.html-css-1-cc-2122.repl.co)

Comment: why do you have a margin left that is that big/useless on your h1?

Comment: Wrap texts in one inline-block element and then `h1 {text-align: center}`

Comment: I don't want a margin that big, but usually if I make small adjustments I can barely see them. I made the margin dramatically big so I could clearly see when the code does work

Comment: If you uncomment your margin-left it works...

Answer (score 0):

```css
    div, div.menu {
        width: 80%;
        height: 60%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-top: 7%;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
       display: inline-block;
       text-align:center;
    }
    h1 > span {
       font-size: 50px; 
       text-decoration: none; 
       text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ffffff; 
       color:#f5cec9;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="menu">
        <h1><span>Welcome!</span><br>What do you want to make?</h1>
    </div>
```

1. Move your inline CSS into a CSS class/identifier (span)
2. Set your H1 wrapper tag to "inline-block" to retain margin values
3. Set your text to centered to centered the contents text.

Answer (score 0):

Just add "display: inline-block;" to h1:

```css
    img, img.menui {
        width: 165px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
    div, div.cake, div.menu {
        width: 80%;
        height: 60%;
        margin-left: 10%;
        margin-right: 10%;
        margin-top: 7%;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 150px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="menu">
        <h1><span style="font-size: 50px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ffffff; color:#f5cec9;">Welcome!</span><br>What do you want to make?</h1>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin-left` works, you just have to use a realistic value, not billions of pixels like in your (commented)  setting:

```css
img,
img.menui {
  width: 165px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

div,
div.cake,
div.menu {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1><span style="font-size: 50px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ffffff; color:#f5cec9;">Welcome!</span><br>What do you want to make?</h1>
</div>
```

But if you want to center the text, just use `text-align: center` on it:

```css
img,
img.menui {
  width: 165px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

div,
div.cake,
div.menu {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <h1><span style="font-size: 50px; text-decoration: none; text-shadow: 4px 4px 1px #ffffff; color:#f5cec9;">Welcome!</span><br>What do you want to make?</h1>
</div>
```